# Using geopy's vincenty to find distances in pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, geopy

I am trying to use `geopy`'s `vincenty` on each row in a `panda`'s `dataframe`. However, I am unable to get the syntax right in the `lambda` argument. `geopy`'s `vincenty` takes two ordered pair arguments

```
p1 = (lat, long)
p2 = (lat2, long2)
dist = vincenty(p1, p2)
```

What I have tried is:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import vincenty
# read in csv file
jss_loc = pd.read_csv('location.csv', sep = ',')
#
coord_col = ['avg_lat', 'avg_long']
matching_ser_no = jss_loc['ser_no'] == jss_loc['ser_no'].shift(1)
shift_coords = jss_loc.shift(1).loc[matching_ser_no, coord_col]
# join in shifted coords and compute distance
jss_loc_shift = jss_loc.join(shift_coords, how = 'inner', rsuffix = '_2')
jss_loc['hdist'] = jss_loc_shift.apply(lambda ((row['avg_lat'], row['avg_long']), (row['avg_lat_2'], row['avg_long_2'])): 
    vincenty((row['avg_lat'], row['avg_long']), (row['avg_lat_2'], row['avg_long_2'])), axis = 1)
```

The columns of `jss_loc_shift` are: `name`, `id`, `ser_no`, `avg_lat`, `avg_long`, `avg_lat_2`, `avg_long_2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve it.

```
jss_loc_shift['hdist'] = jss_loc_shift.apply(lambda x: vincenty((x[4], x[5]), (x[6], x[7])), axis = 1)
```